# What is the asymptotic value of MAX $(a+b)!(c+d)!b/(a!b!c!d!(b+d))$ if $a+b+c+d=n$?

Tags: catalan-numbers

What is the asymptotic value of

$$\max\ \frac{(a+b)!(c+d)!b}{a!b!c!d!(b+d)}, \quad \textrm{if}\ \  a+b+c+d=n?$$

Is it $\approx 2^n/n$? Is it related to the asymptotic value of the Catalan numbers?

Comment: For some intuition, look at the easy case, where $a=b=c=d=n/4$.

Comment: yup! that is the intution. In fact maximum value of binomial coefficient also indicates that. But is there any proof?

Comment: For @Paul's case, I get $2^n$, not $2^n/n$.

Comment: may I have the deduction?